# MemoryStream with wait till there is something to read

Tags: c#, asynchronous, stream

This is the very simple question, but I can not seems figure this out without talking to somebody.

I need a Stream like MemoryStream that will asynchronously block on read till there is something to read OR timeout elapsed.

**Update:**
Ok. I've gave up and wrote the Wrapper class bymyself, but EndRead always returns 0. Please look at the code below. (Do not offer the Task oriented solutions.)

```
    public class BlockingMemoryStream : MemoryStream
    {
        ManualResetEventSlim isReadReady = new ManualResetEventSlim(false);

        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
        {
            base.Write(buffer, offset, count);
            //base.Position = offset; //I do not know if I need this!!!!
            isReadReady.Set();
        }

        public override IAsyncResult BeginRead(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
        {
            IAsyncResult result = base.BeginRead(buffer, offset, count, callback, state);
            return result;
        }

        public override int EndRead(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
        {
            isReadReady.Wait(/*600000*/);
            int aa = base.EndRead(asyncResult);
            return aa;
        }
    }
```

Comment: The context isn't clear or obvious. How would it be written to?

Comment: Please look at C.Evenhuis code. That that code that is what I am trying to avoid.

Comment: If you really only want an answer that involves an existing implementation in .NET itself, I don't think you're going to get that. A simple timeout-enabled `Stream` wrapper can be implemented without too much trouble (the current answers notwithstanding), but I guess there's no point in providing that if you're only interested in something that already exists in .NET.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, what this does is just loops through and waits till there is object to be read.

```
    private static readonly MemoryStream _reader;
    private static object _data;

    static Program()
    {
        _reader = new MemoryStream();
    }

    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Task.Run(async delegate()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                if (_data == null)
                    await Task.Delay(1000); // so the cpu can have rest
                                            // you can lower the value of this
                else
                {
                    // read here
                    await Task.Delay(1000);
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want a stream to which you write, and another thread reads from. You could roll your own, ie:

```
public sealed class MyStream : Stream
{
    private readonly MemoryStream underlyingStream = new MemoryStream();
    private readonly AutoResetEvent waitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);

    public int Timeout { get; set; }

    public MyStream()
    {
        Timeout = 5000;
    }

    public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        // Write to the stream and notify any waiting threads
        underlyingStream.Write(buffer, offset, count);
        waitHandle.Set();
    }

    public override int Read(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
    {
        int bytes;
        while ((bytes = underlyingStream.Read(buffer, offset, count)) == 0)
        {
            // 0 bytes read (end of stream), wait Timeout ms for someone to write
            if (!waitHandle.WaitOne(Timeout))
            {
                throw new TimeoutException();
            }
        }

        return bytes;
    }

    // TODO other mandatory methods
}
```

I wrote the above example without testing and the implementation of `Stream` is incomplete, it just shows a possible direction for your solution. If multiple threads are `Read`ing from it, it may take a multitude of `Timeout` to complete.

You could also use sockets over the TCP loopback and use `NetworkStream` if you don't like fiddling with wait handles.

Comment: Thank you! I've considered to implement this, but I hoped that there is something already buildin in C#. NetworkStream is not good - it requires too many dummy veriables.

Comment: This answer is fundamentally wrong, even if the OP was willing to accept a non-built-in implementation: when a `Read()` operation returns 0 bytes, that signals the end of the `Stream`. There won't ever be any more bytes at that point, no matter how long you wait.

Comment: @PeterDuniho I appreciate the comment, you're right, it should throw `TimeoutException` and I will correct my answer. I don't think it's _fundamentally_ wrong though, I provided both an idea for a custom solution and a built-in one.